# Horizontally merge dataframes in R - text mining

Tags: r, merge, text-mining

How do i horizontally merge/combine 3 dataframes in R? I have three dataframes that have a word in one column, and the word count extracted from a text in the next, kind of like this:

```
  word.        count
1 hello.         6
2 test.          3
3 how.           8
4 are.           4
5 you.           1
```

and let's say dataframe 2:

```
  word.        count
1 hello.         6
2 test.          3
3 i.             3
4 am.            6
5 good.          2
```

how do i merge them like this:

```
  word.         df1.     df2.      total
1 hello.         6.       6.         12
2 test.          3        3           6
3 how.           8        0.          8 
4 are.           4        0           4
5 you.           1        0           1
6 i              0        3           3
7 am             0        6           6
8 good           0        2           2
```

instead of 2 dataframes, i thus have 3

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `merge()`? Maybe something along the lines of `merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "word.")`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each has the same joining column:

```r
out <- Reduce(function(a,b) merge(a, b, by = "word.", all = TRUE),
              list(df1, df2))
# normally this has `NA` in not-shared words, convert these NAs to 0
out[,-1] <- lapply(out[,-1], function(a) replace(a, is.na(a), 0))
out
#    word. count.x count.y
# 1    am.       0       6
# 2   are.       4       0
# 3  good.       0       2
# 4 hello.       6       6
# 5   how.       8       0
# 6     i.       0       3
# 7  test.       3       3
# 8   you.       1       0
```

However many frames you have, put them all in a `list` and this just works. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358272 for discussion of "list of frames" efficiencies.)

All you need to do now is change the column names. (Many techniques for doing this.)

---

Data

```r
df1 <- structure(list(word. = c("hello.", "test.", "how.", "are.", "you."), count = c(6L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
df2 <- structure(list(word. = c("hello.", "test.", "i.", "am.", "good."), count = c(6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Most R functions that do merge, or using a more technical term, do a join operation between tables, are designed to be used on two tables at a time. In `base` R, we have the `merge` function for these join operation's. Since you have more than two tables to merge, even with this behaviour, you can easily replicate te join's accross your tables, with the `Reduce` function. Like defined below:

**Here are the input data:**

```
word <- c("hello.", "test.", "how.", "are.", "you.") 

df1 <- data.frame(
  word = word,
  count = 11:15
)

set.seed(1)
df2 <- data.frame(
  word = sample(word, size = 8, replace = T),
  value2 = rnorm(8)
)

set.seed(1)
df3 <- data.frame(
  word = word[c(3,4)],
  value3 = rnorm(2)
)
```

**Here are the operation of join:**

```
list_dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3)

multi_inner <- Reduce(
  function(x, y, ...) merge(x, y, by = "word", all = TRUE), 
  list_dfs
)
```

**Here is the result:**

```
    word count       value2     value3
1   are.    14 -0.294720447  0.1836433
2 hello.    11 -0.928567035         NA
3 hello.    11 -0.005767173         NA
4   how.    13 -0.799009249 -0.6264538
5   how.    13 -0.289461574 -0.6264538
6  test.    12  2.404653389         NA
7  test.    12 -1.147657009         NA
8   you.    15  0.763593461         NA
```

Now, in this example, I am considering that you want to save all the possible combinations between the 3 tables. If you just want to identify, the matches (or the words in the `word` column) that appears in all of your tables, you need to set the `all` argument to FALSE. Like this:

```
multi_inner <- Reduce(
  function(x, y, ...) merge(x, y, by = "word", all = FALSE), 
  list_dfs
)
```

**Resulting this:**

```
  word count     value2     value3
1 are.    14 -0.2947204  0.1836433
2 how.    13 -0.7990092 -0.6264538
3 how.    13 -0.2894616 -0.6264538
```